# Java TableView not populating only one column

Tags: java

I cannot seem to get one of my Table View columns to populate.  The column with the issue is my 'complianceReq'.  It is strange because if I swap my 'brandName' into the 'complianceReq' it will show the brand name information correctly.  However I cannot seem to get the 'complianceReq' to show up.  I have tried to use both boolean and a String version with no success.

I can confirm the variables do have true/false or Yes/No depending on which version I'm trying.

I can also see that the Getter method is not being called as well.

The code for the classes i'm using is here: `https://pastebin.com/gswutwk0`

This is my Controller Class:

```
private DBReader dbr;

@FXML
public TableView<JobSummaryData> tblView;

@FXML
public void updateTable() {

    ObservableList<JobSummaryData> obLst = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dbr.getJobSummary());

    tblView.getColumns().clear();
    tblView.setItems(obLst);

    TableColumn<JobSummaryData,Integer> colJobItem = new TableColumn<JobSummaryData,Integer>("Job Item Id");
    colJobItem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JobSummaryData,Integer>("jobItemId"));

    TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String> colBrandName = new TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String>("Brand Name");
    colBrandName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JobSummaryData,String>("brandName"));

    TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String> colCompliance = new TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String>("Compliance Required");
    colCompliance.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JobSummaryData,String>("complianceReq"));

    TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String> colLink = new TableColumn<JobSummaryData,String>("Survey Link");
    colLink.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JobSummaryData,String>("surveyLink"));

    tblView.getColumns().addAll(colJobItem, colBrandName, colCompliance, colLink);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    dbr = new DBReader();
}
```

This is my JobSummaryData class:

```
private int jobItemId, submittedMinutes;
private String brandName, storeId, storeName, storeLocation, jobType, status, merchandiserName, agentNumber, areaManagerName, uncompleteReason; //complianceReq
private String eMail, mobile, surveyLink; //TBA Pref contact method
private boolean complianceRequired;
private Date jobDate;

public JobSummaryData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    jobItemId = rs.getInt("jobitemid");
    submittedMinutes = rs.getInt("submittedminutes");

    brandName = rs.getString("brandname");

    storeId = rs.getString("storeid");
    storeName = rs.getString("storename");
    storeLocation = rs.getString("storelocation");
    jobType = rs.getString("jobtype");
    status = rs.getString("Status");
    merchandiserName = rs.getString("merchandisername");
    agentNumber = rs.getString("agentnumber");
    areaManagerName = rs.getString("areamanagername");
    uncompleteReason = rs.getString("uncompletereason");

    eMail = rs.getString("Email");
    mobile = rs.getString("Mobile");
    surveyLink = rs.getString("SurveyLink");        

    complianceRequired = rs.getBoolean("ComplianceRequired");
    /*if(rs.getBoolean("ComplianceRequired")) {
        complianceReq = "Yes";
    }
    else {
        complianceReq = "No";
    }*/

    jobDate = rs.getDate("jobdate");
}

public int getJobItemId() {return jobItemId;}
public int getSubmittedMins() {return submittedMinutes;}

public String getBrandName() {return brandName;}
public String getStoreId() {return storeId;}
public String getStoreName() {return storeName;}
public String getStoreLocation() {return storeLocation;}
public String getJobType() {return jobType;}
public String getJobStatus() {return status;}
public String getMerchName() {return merchandiserName;}
public String getAgentNum() {return agentNumber;}
public String getAreaManagerNum() {return areaManagerName;}
public String getUncompReason() {return uncompleteReason;}

public String getEMail() {return eMail;}
public String getMobile() {return mobile;}
public String getSurveyLink() {return surveyLink;}

//public String getComplianceRequired() {return complianceReq;}
public boolean getComplianceBool() {return complianceRequired;}

public Date getJobDate() {return jobDate;}
```

What have I missed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `"complianceReq"` to the `PropertyValueFactory` but you have no `getComplianceReq()` method in your `JobSummaryData` class. The `PropertyValueFactory` class requires the getters and setters follow Java Bean naming conventions.

Change either the cell value factory to:

```
colCompliance.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("complianceRequired"));
```

**Or** change the getter in your `JobSummaryData` class to:

```
public String getComplianceReq() { return complianceReq; }
```

If you ever implement JavaFX properties for your `JobSummaryData` class, don't forget to add the correctly named property-getter—`complianceRequiredProperty()` or `complianceReqProperty()`, depending.